# Overlapping <li elements - CSS customsing

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm writing in regards to an issue I've encountered with the css coding for the hovering navigation bar and its tabs dropdown menu options. The link to my blogger blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com.

I have three tabs/pages in the hovering navigation bar that have dropdown menu options that appear when the mouse/cursor hovers over the relevant text. The issue I'm having however is that when the cursor or mouse hovers over one of the tabs/pages text - in this case they are titled 'Blankesque', 'Social' and 'Features' - the dropdown menu options overlap the tabs/pages title. Ideally I would like to have the dropdown menu options to appear below the relevant titles instead of overlapping and covering them.

I have included the html and css coding below.

```
#wctopdropcont{ /* width of the main bar categories */
width:100%;
height:40px;
display:block;
padding: 0;
margin-left: -16px;

z-index:100;
top:0px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;

background:#ffffff;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  }

#wctopdropnav{ /* social */
float: right;
width:97%;
height:7px;
display:block;
padding:0;
margin-left:30px;
}
#wctopdropnav ul{
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
#wctopdropnav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
line-height:35px;
margin:0;
padding:6.5px;/* height of the clicked bar */
background:#ffffff;
}

#wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link{
color:#000000;
float:right;
display:block;
margin: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font:11px cantarell!important;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing : 0.13em;
}
#wctopdropnav li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li a:active, #wctopdropnav .current_page_item a  {
color:black;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
background: white; /* Old browsers */
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
filter:black;   
}
#wctopdropnav li li a, #wctopdropnav li li a:link, #wctopdropnav li li  a:visited{
font-size: 11px;
background:#ffffff;
color: #000000;
width: 90px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 1px;
line-height:20px;
position: relative;
}
#wctopdropnav li li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li li a:active {
color: black;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
background: white;
filter: white; 
}

#wctopdropnav li ul{
z-index:9999;
position:absolute;
left:-999em;
height:auto;
width:170px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li li li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover ul, #topwctopdropnav li li.sfhover ul, #topwctopdropnav li li li.sfhover ul{
left:auto
}
#wctopdropnav li:hover, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover{
position:static
}
#dptuh {
color: #000000;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: cantarell;
font-size: 16px!important;
display: block;
letter-spacing: 0.13em;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0.9%;
  }
#dptuh a {
font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<div id='wctopdropcont'>
 <div id='wctopdropnav'>
     <ul>
       <li><a href='#'>Blankesque</a> 
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/about-blankesque-blog.html'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/disclaimer-policy_13.html'>Policies</a></li>
         </ul></li>

<li><a href='#'>Social</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque'>Pinterest</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/itsblankesque.com'>Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/people/aladyinwhite-8315551'>Bloglovin</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.instagram.com/blankesque/blankesquexo'>Instagram</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>Features</a>

         <ul>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Beauty'>Beauty</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Creative'>Creative</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fashion'>Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Favourites'>Favourites</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fragrance'>Fragrance</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Hair'>Hair</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Haul'>Haul</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Life'>Life</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Skincare'>Skincare</a></li>
       </ul>
       </li>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/contact-blankesque-for-press.html'>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>

<div id='dptuh'>
<a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Blankesque</a>
   </div>

</div></div>
```

Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: Have you tried positioning the lists with "top"? Use top: (amount)em; and keep adding values ti'll you get it where it need to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#wctopdropnav li ul{
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    height:auto;
    width:170px;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    padding:0px;
    }
```